# Binary Sorting logic: not sorting numbers correctly

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to implement binary sort logic. I start by generating random numbers. Then create a copy of that array which will be then sorted out with the Binary Sort method. The problem is that the sort is not working properly. I am not sure if my comparisons are being done correctly. Any ideas why is not sorting properly?

```
namespace binarySort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Random r = new Random();
        OpenFileDialog open1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        long operations = 0;
        int size;
        int max;
        int[] createArray;
        int[] sortArray;
        int[] copyArray;


 public void RandomNumber()
        {
            size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
            max = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);
            createArray = new int[size];
            copyArray = new int[size];
            sortArray = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                createArray[i] = r.Next(1, max);
            }

            textBoxResults.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + "Random" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            DisplayArrays();
        }


public void BinarySort()
        {
            operations = 0;
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            int low = 0;
            int high = 0;
            int temp = 0;
            int mid = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                copyArray[i] = createArray[i];
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                high = i - 1;
                temp = copyArray[i];

                while (low <= high)
                {
                    operations++;

                    mid = (low + high) / 2;

                    if (temp < copyArray[mid])
                    {
                        high = mid - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        low = mid + 1;
                    }
                }

                operations++;

                for (int j = i - 1; j >= low; j--)
                {
                    copyArray[j + 1] = copyArray[j];
                }

                copyArray[low] = temp;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                sortArray[i] = copyArray[i];
            }

            textBoxResults.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + "Binary Insertion" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            DisplaySorted();

        }

 private void buttonSortArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    BinarySort();

    }

}

}
```

**For example:**

[image]

Comment: When you step through the code, at what point does the array first contain the wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Sorry, your original code is OK, you just need to add this line `low = 0;` after `high = i - 1;` so it should be

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
 {
        high = i - 1;
        low = 0;
        temp = copyArray[i];
```

Comment: after making that change you suggested i get this error now: `Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: This is perfect, you fixed it! Thank you.